# Call PowerShell From WinRT App

Tags: powershell, windows-runtime

I was wondering if there is a way to execute PowerShell scripts from WinRT apps. Specifically, I'd like to call Hyper-V cmdlets such as Get-VM and display the results in the <strike>Metro</strike> new Windows UI.

Or is there any other idea how to accomplish that? I've seen the Hyper-V Manager app on the Windows Store, does anybody happen to know how these guys do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there isn't a direct way in code to do this i.e. you can't host the PowerShell engine.  However, if you are industrious, you could use WinRT socket support to either connect to a PowerShell Web Access port or a PowerShell remoting endpoint.  Although the latter would likely take some heavy lifting to figure out the WSMan protocol.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks a lot, though.